# Confirm submit to specific page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that has two different submit-buttons that should submit to different pages.

HTML:

```
<form id="campaign" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="submit" value="Promote!" name="ap_promote" onsubmit="promote('?page=campaigns&id=<?php echo $campaigns_id?>&edit=true&test=2')" id="ap_promote">

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function promote(action)
    {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to promote this campaign?'))
        {
            document.getElementById('campaign').action = action;
            document.getElementById('campaign').submit();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As you see, it should send the form to `?page=campaigns&id=#&test=2`. The problem is that it doesn't show any confirmation box and it just sends the form to itself, and not to the specified url.

Comment: Usually when this happens there is a JavaScript error handling the submit process. Your action attribute doesn't actually set the page to load just the query string. The action attribute needs to look like: mypage.html?page=campaign....

Comment: Well, all buttons uses same page, but with different query strings. So it should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons don't have `onsubmit` event, it's a form event. Since you plan to have different actions per depending on clicked button, you can use combination of button `onclick` and form `onsubmit` events. Check it out:

```
<form id="campaign" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return promote()">
    <input type="submit" value="Promote!" name="ap_promote" onclick="this.form.action='one'" id="ap_promote" />
    <input type="submit" value="Promote!" name="ap_promote" onclick="this.form.action='two'" id="ap_promote" />
</form>
```

And JS code becomes as simple as:

```
function promote() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to promote this campaign?');
}
```

Comment: Works flawlessly! Clean and simple code. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Change `onsubmit="promote(..."` to `onsubmit="return promote(..."` in your button click handler

Comment: Buttons don't have onsubmit event.

Comment: I used onclick and added "return". Didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.
You should use the button instead of submit button

```
<form id="campaign" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="button" value="Promote!" name="ap_promote" onclick="promote('?page=campaigns&id=<?php echo $campaigns_id?>&edit=true&test=2')" id="ap_promote">

</form>
```